# Setting Segment ajs_anonymous_id from SSR on client if user doesn't have cookie with Next.js App?

Tags: google-analytics, next.js, segment-analytics

Anyone set the `ajs_anonymous_id` in SSR (Next.js) if it doesn't currently exist on client?

I have a need to "read" the `ajs_anonymous_id` (Segment analytics) cookie during a SSR rendering in Next.Js, but of course there are instances when that cookie does not exist yet ie...person hasn't visited my site before and thus never go it... BUT, since i need in SSR side..... I was hoping there is a process I can "set it" on the server side so that I can use it, THEN have it on the client too... so..

Client visits page

Has `ajs_anonymous_id` cookie, cool, use it and do some display things....

Does not have `ajs_anonymous_id`, I seed the `ajs_anonymous_id` (drop a cookie) and then do some display things.

Pages loads.. My analytics file (that loads on the font end thru a containe) sees there is an already `ajs_anonymous_id` cookie, cool.

Anyone have an example of this or how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah - there seems to be a package and method just for this.

```
import Analytics from 'analytics-node'

// if no anonymousId, send a randomly generated one
  // otherwise grab existing to include in call to segment
  let anonymousId
  if (cookies.ajs_anonymous_id) {
    anonymousId = cookies.ajs_anonymous_id
  } else {
    anonymousId = = uuid.v4()
    res.cookie('ajs_anonymous_id', anonymousId )
  }
```

for the full example, i'd refer to their docs:
https://segment.com/docs/guides/how-to-guides/collect-pageviews-serverside/

For NextJS, I expect you have to move away from their server default implementation and build a wrapper to allow you to add this type of middleware.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const next = require('next');

const host = process.env.LOCAL_ADDRESS || '0.0.0.0';
const port = parseInt(process.env.NODE_PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev, dir: 'app' });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();

    server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    server.set('trust proxy', true);

    server.use(customMiddleware);

    server.all('*', (req, ...args) => {
        // Log the request only if we need to (we don't log all static asset requests)
        if (req.log) {
            req.log.info('incoming request');
        }

        return handle(req, ...args);
    });

    server.listen(port, host, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`> Ready on http://${host}:${port}`);
    });
});
```

then start the app with `node app/server`

Hope that helps to get you started!

Comment: I didn't see this till now. Thanks. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Using Next.js middleware:

```
// middleware.ts

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const response = NextResponse.next();

  const anonymousIdCookieName = 'ajs_anonymous_id';

  const cookieAnonymousId = request.cookies.get(anonymousIdCookieName)?.value;

  let anonymousId;

  if (cookieAnonymousId) {
    anonymousId = cookieAnonymousId;
  } else {
    anonymousId = uuid();
    response.cookies.set(anonymousIdCookieName, anonymousId);
  }

  return response;
}
```